# создание экземпляров класса

Tags: c++

Как сделать так, чтобы можно было создать экземпляр класса `B` только после того, как был создан экземпляр класса `A`?

Comment: Вы бы лучше свою задачу описали. То, что Вы спрашиваете, похоже на попытку неправильного решения какой-то проблемы

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Конструктор `B` должен принимать `A` или какой-то объект, который можно получить только от `A`:

```
struct B {
  B(const A&);
};
```

Comment: А иначе никак??

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу можно трактовать двояко. Если как "если в программе не создан ни один `A`, то создание `B` должно сгенерировать исключение" - то это одно... Тут я бы предложил в классе `A` отслеживать наличие с помощью, например, переменной класса (не экземпляра) и проверять ее в конструкторе класса `B`.

Если же нужно, чтобы до создания `B` был обязательно создан - где угодно, какой угодно - объект `A`, то можно использовать статическую переменную `A` в конструкторе `B`. Еще проще вариант - добавить объект `A` в класс `B` в качестве члена - тогда он обязательно создастся до создания `B`.